# Show me a better way! How to unnest a heavily nested list in R

Tags: r, nested-lists

I will start off by stating that I have working code, but it is embarrassingly inefficient and clumsy. I was hoping that someone in the community might be able to show me a better way to unnest this heavily nested list.

As a background, it is transaction data on nfts that is heavily nested. I am just trying to get a data frame out, ultimately down to the daily level. I have managed to get the code working for the totalPriceUSD field, but as I mentioned, it is clumsy.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlist)
library(jsonlite)

mydata <- fromJSON("https://api2.cryptoslam.io/api/nft-indexes/NFTGlobal")

#attempt at nested extraction
mydata <- rlist::list.flatten(mydata) %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
mydata <- select(mydata1, contains("totalPriceUSD"))
mydata <- select(mydata1, contains("daily"))

#change row name
rownames(mydata) <- "totalPriceUSD"
names(mydata) <- substring(names(mydata),24,33)

#change col names
names(mydata) <- format(as.Date(names(mydata), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

mydata1 <- mydata %>%
  gather(date, totalPriceUSD)

mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)
mydata$date <- as.Date(mydata$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

As I said, it works, but it ain't pretty. Any suggestions on improving this?

Many thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Apologies - didn't know that existed! I will use it in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
mydata <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api2.cryptoslam.io/api/nft-indexes/NFTGlobal")
monthly <- bind_rows(lapply(mydata, `[[`, "monthlySummary"), .id = "monthly_id")
daily <- bind_rows(lapply(mydata, function(z) bind_rows(z[["dailySummaries"]], .id = "daily_id")), .id = "monthly_id")

monthly
# # A tibble: 60 x 6
#    monthly_id totalTransactions uniqueBuyers uniqueSellers totalPriceUSD isRollingHoursData
#    <chr>                  <int>        <int>         <int>         <dbl> <lgl>             
#  1 2017-06                  193           33            32        11570. FALSE             
#  2 2017-07                  613           61            57        89111. FALSE             
#  3 2017-08                  113           36            31        15133. FALSE             
#  4 2017-09                   63           22            19         5154. FALSE             
#  5 2017-10                   52           17            11         3041. FALSE             
#  6 2017-11                 7259         1077           508        72760. FALSE             
#  7 2017-12               265412        53406         23137     18804813. FALSE             
#  8 2018-01                30693         7682          4582      1360558. FALSE             
#  9 2018-02                34177         4142          4364      2931369. FALSE             
# 10 2018-03                29051         3752          2784       987256. FALSE             
# # ... with 50 more rows

daily
# # A tibble: 1,750 x 7
#    monthly_id daily_id            totalTransactions uniqueBuyers uniqueSellers totalPriceUSD isRollingHoursData
#    <chr>      <chr>                           <int>        <int>         <int>         <dbl> <lgl>             
#  1 2017-06    2017-06-23T00:00:00                27            9             6         1456. FALSE             
#  2 2017-06    2017-06-24T00:00:00                15            7             8          846. FALSE             
#  3 2017-06    2017-06-25T00:00:00                15            7             5          594. FALSE             
#  4 2017-06    2017-06-26T00:00:00                23           10            12         1076. FALSE             
#  5 2017-06    2017-06-27T00:00:00                35            8            15         2091. FALSE             
#  6 2017-06    2017-06-28T00:00:00                15            6             5         1431. FALSE             
#  7 2017-06    2017-06-29T00:00:00                41           13            11         2302. FALSE             
#  8 2017-06    2017-06-30T00:00:00                22           11             7         1775. FALSE             
#  9 2017-07    2017-07-01T00:00:00                12            7            10         3727. FALSE             
# 10 2017-07    2017-07-02T00:00:00                34           13            12         3117. FALSE             
# # ... with 1,740 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @r2evans answer using `rrapply()` + `unnest_wider()`. This should generalize to arbitrary levels of nesting as well.

```
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(rrapply)

mydata <- fromJSON("https://api2.cryptoslam.io/api/nft-indexes/NFTGlobal")

monthly <- rrapply(mydata, classes = "list", condition = \(x, .xname) .xname == "monthlySummary", how = "melt") |>
  unnest_wider(value)

daily <- rrapply(mydata, classes = "list", condition = \(x, .xparents) "dailySummaries" %in% head(.xparents, -1), how = "melt") |>
  unnest_wider(value) 

monthly
#> # A tibble: 60 × 9
#>    L1      L2          totalTransactio… uniqueBuyers uniqueSellers totalPriceUSD
#>    <chr>   <chr>                  <int>        <int>         <int>         <dbl>
#>  1 2017-06 monthlySum…              193           33            32        11570.
#>  2 2017-07 monthlySum…              613           61            57        89111.
#>  3 2017-08 monthlySum…              113           36            31        15133.
#>  4 2017-09 monthlySum…               63           22            19         5154.
#>  5 2017-10 monthlySum…               52           17            11         3041.
#>  6 2017-11 monthlySum…             7259         1077           508        72760.
#>  7 2017-12 monthlySum…           265412        53406         23137     18804813.
#>  8 2018-01 monthlySum…            30693         7682          4582      1360558.
#>  9 2018-02 monthlySum…            34177         4142          4364      2931369.
#> 10 2018-03 monthlySum…            29051         3752          2784       987256.
#> # … with 50 more rows, and 3 more variables: isRollingHoursData <lgl>,
#> #   productNames <lgl>, productNamesWithoutAnySale <lgl>

daily
#> # A tibble: 1,750 × 10
#>    L1      L2    L3    totalTransactio… uniqueBuyers uniqueSellers totalPriceUSD
#>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>            <int>        <int>         <int>         <dbl>
#>  1 2017-06 dail… 2017…               27            9             6         1456.
#>  2 2017-06 dail… 2017…               15            7             8          846.
#>  3 2017-06 dail… 2017…               15            7             5          594.
#>  4 2017-06 dail… 2017…               23           10            12         1076.
#>  5 2017-06 dail… 2017…               35            8            15         2091.
#>  6 2017-06 dail… 2017…               15            6             5         1431.
#>  7 2017-06 dail… 2017…               41           13            11         2302.
#>  8 2017-06 dail… 2017…               22           11             7         1775.
#>  9 2017-07 dail… 2017…               12            7            10         3727.
#> 10 2017-07 dail… 2017…               34           13            12         3117.
#> # … with 1,740 more rows, and 3 more variables: isRollingHoursData <lgl>,
#> #   productNames <lgl>, productNamesWithoutAnySale <lgl>
```

Comment: This implementation also worked for those following at home. Thank you for the help!